# Sign In With Apple ID AKAuthenticationError Code=-7014

Tags: xcode, authentication, sign-in-with-apple, tvos13

I have been trying to implement Apple ID Sign in for both iOS and tvOS applications. iOS is able to sign in with Apple ID just fine, but whenever I tried to sign in through our tvOS app, it shows a generic unknown error in the UI (error 1000) and in the debug log, it gives me the following error:

[core] Authorization failed: Error Domain=AKAuthenticationError Code=-7014 "(null)" UserInfo={AKClientBundleID=[bundleID]}

I use this code below that follows the basic steps for Apple ID Sign In:

```
@IBAction func signInbuttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
        let request = appleIDProvider.createRequest()
        request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]

        let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
        authorizationController.delegate = self
        authorizationController.presentationContextProvider = self
        authorizationController.performRequests()
    }
```

I have "Sign in With Apple" capabilities Turned on in XCode, and our Identifier for tvOS app is using the same Group App ID as the iOS Identifier so it seems to be fine. There isn't any forums that give this exact error. Does anyone know about what error code -7104 means, and what can I do to resolve it? Thank you.